# Ember.js - Filtering all properties of a model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, filter

I am trying to filter all properties of a model by an input field in Ember.js. If the text field input is found in one of the models properties, I want to return the filtered results.

I already have a working solution, but i wanted to know if there is a better way to filter all properties, instead of getting them one after another. I already did a lot of research, but I could not find any better way to solve this problem. Here is the relevant code:

**Model**:

```
[
  {
    "source": "this is a source", 
    "title": "this is a title",
    "message":"this is a message"
  },
  {
    "source": "this is a source too", 
    "title": "this is a title too",
    "message":"this is a message too"
  }
]
```

**Filter**:

```
 export default Ember.Component.extend({

  filterText: "", //Input field value

  filteredArticles: Ember.computed('filterText', function () {
    var filter = this.get('filterText').toLowerCase();
    return this.get('model').filter(function (item) {
      return item.get('title').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 ||
        item.get('message').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 ||
        item.get('source').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1
    });
  })
});
```

So is there a way to get all properties with one command (e.g. like *item.get('allProperties')*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all Ember Object [`getProperties`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_getProperties) method is available.

If this is not an Ember Object, then you can use [`Ember.getProperties`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_getProperties)

But again those method return object with specified properties, not the values alone you are looking for. So your approach is correct, only if you are dealing with two or three properties in `model` object. if you think you will get more properties or dynamically you will add more properties to model object then you can do object iteration inside `filter` call back.

```
filterdText: Ember.computed('filterText',function(){
    var filter = this.get('filterText').toLowerCase();
    return this.get('model').filter((item,index) =>{ 
      for(var key in item){
        if( item.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          if(item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1){
            return true
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    })    
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Somehow your suggested solution is not working for me. Before the _hasOwnProperty_ check, the key variable does not only contain the models properties but also properties like "__debugInfo_" or "__internalModel_". After the _hasOwnProperty_ check, the key does not even contain the models properties. I did check  it with console logs. Any ideas?

Comment: check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/66477278e5e06bf328dd7aaaa8cc7bb6?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C).. may be you can post the route model hook.

Comment: I once again tried to use your code, but this time the key only contains the property "store". I'm using the Ember Data store to retrieve the models data. Check this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1065123730e9fe92a61eef81468b405b) for all the relevant code.

Comment: Problem is not with filter stuff code. this should work for normal array and RecordArray. Problem lies else where I doubt your `normalizeFindAllResponse` response not aligned with response you got from server. so make sure you filled data in store for the particular model `articles/top`. you can see the store by using Ember-Inspector plugin.

Comment: This is strange. With Ember Inspector I'm able to see, that all the needed properties are actually set in the Ember Data store, but the _OwnProperties Tab_ only lists following properties: _store_, _currentState_, _adapterError_ and _OWNER [id=__ember1476379556355829517478938]_. I couldn't figure out the problem yet, but your filter solution seems to be right anyway.